# Php, Как удалить символ " при парсинге?

Tags: php

Страница откуда деру текст выглядит так:

```
<tr class="now">
<td class="when">lbbb</td>
<td><a href="/result?q=&quot;r sweeney&quot; Parramatta">"r sweeney" Parramatta</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="when">lbbb</td>
<td><a href="/result?q=&quot;henry Thomas muggridge&quot; divorce">"henry Thomas muggridge" divorce</a></td>
 </tr>
```

**Вывод делаю так:**

```
<?php
$trendurl = 'http://sdfsdfsd.com/parserurl';
$gtrend = curl_init();
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, sprintf("Mozilla/%d.0",rand(4,5)));
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_URL,$trendurl);
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($gtrend, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$trend = curl_exec($gtrend);
preg_match_all("/<a href=\"[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/is", $trend, $keywords, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

$i=27;
while ($i<37)
{
$seourl = $keywords[1];
$seourl = str_replace(' ', '+', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace('www.', '', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace('http://', '', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace('https://', '', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace('.', '', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace('"', '', $seourl );
$seourl = str_replace('~', ' ', $seourl);
$seourl = str_replace(',', ' ', $seourl);
$r = $seourl[$i]; 
?>
<li><a href="/q_<?php echo strtolower($r); ?>"><?php echo $keywords[1][$i]; ?></a></li>
<?php
    $i++;
}
curl_close($gtrend);
?>
```

**Как убрать "? Нужно чтобы вывело чистый код, без символа"**

Comment: Что убрать то нужно, кавычки или `&quot;`? Откуда, из адреса или текста ссылки? Попробуйте выражаться яснее

Comment: Спасибо, сделал так, как вы написали $seourl = str_replace('&quot;', '', $seourl );  Теперь все работает